# Datepicker value assign to a dropdown

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, dropdown

I'm developing my app and what I want to do is as I select a date on the calendar, the selected date specifically the month, the date and the year will be the the dropdowns' value. Each attribute for example a month is for one dropdown the the next is for anther dropdown

here's my code for the select

```
  <select ng-disabled="isCheckboxSelected('1')" ng-model="ngModel">
       <option ng-value=" {{ngModel | date: 'MM'}}"
      </option>
  </select>
```

my datepicker is

```
<input
    type="date"
    ng-disabled="isCheckboxSelected('1')"
    id="test"
    name="date"
    ng-model="ngModel"
    popup="d MMM yyyy"
    options="dateOptions"
     ng-click="Opened=true"
     ng-change="saveNewDate"
     custom-datepicker/>
```

Im using AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

By using $watch on your calendar control you can assign your date values to drop downs.

Here is the basic version for same. If the date is going to be select once then you does not need array for month,date and year. In that case a simple variable is enough for value binding.

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.month = [];
    $scope.day = [];
    $scope.year = [];

    $scope.$watch('myDate', function(newValue) {
        if (newValue != undefined) {
            if ($scope.month.indexOf($filter('date')(newValue, 'MM')) == -1) {
                $scope.month.push($filter('date')(newValue, 'MM'));
            }

            if ($scope.day.indexOf($filter('date')(newValue, 'dd')) == -1) {
                $scope.day.push($filter('date')(newValue, 'dd'));
            }

            if ($scope.year.indexOf($filter('date')(newValue, 'yyyy')) == -1) {
                $scope.year.push($filter('date')(newValue, 'yyyy'));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <h2>Todo</h2>

    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <table width="70%">
            <tr>
                <td>Calender :</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="date" ng-disabled="isCheckboxSelected('1')" id="test" name="date" ng-model="myDate" popup="d MMM yyyy" options="dateOptions" ng-click="Opened=true" ng-change="saveNewDate" custom-datepicker/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date :</td>
                <td>
                    <select data-ng-model="daySelected" data-ng-options="c as c for c in day">
                        <option value="">-- Select Day --</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Month :</td>
                <td>
                    <select data-ng-model="monthSelected" data-ng-options="c as c for c in month">
                        <option value="">-- Select Month --</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Year :</td>
                <td>
                    <select data-ng-model="yearSelected" data-ng-options="c as c for c in year">
                        <option value="">-- Select Year --</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9ywwenj/)

Comment: Thank you but this code transfers only the selected data individually on the dropdown list. What I want to happen is that, after selecting the date on the calendar, the dropdown will automatically select the same data picked on the calendar and not just to add the selected data on the list. Thank You @J-D :)